# Why libcurl doesn't upgrade connection to HTTP/2?

Tags: curl, post, libcurl, http2

I want to send POST to website that supports HTTP/2 but libcurl doesn't use that HTTP version, instead it uses 1.1 and program 'beep' when displays response (binary data). What can I do to properly show response and use HTTP/2?

What have I done to solve problem:
-builded libcurl with **nghttp2** and **OpenSSL**,
-changed library **CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION** option to **CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0**,

Answer (score 0):

your binary data is a separate problem, but to force libcurl to use http2, if you know the target server supports it, try setting `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` 
 to `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE`

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE);
```

as for your binary data issue... that is probably a bugged http server that sends the response compressed, even when the request did not specify an "Accept-Encoding" headers... set CURLOPT_VERBOSE to 1 to verify (if your request doesn't contain the header "Accept-Encoding", and the response contains the "Encoding:" header, there's your binary problem. to solve it, it's usually sufficient to set CURLOPT_ENCODING to emptystring, then curl will try to decompress it for you automatically, provided that it's an encoding curl actually supports. otherwise, you need to decompress it yourself.)